# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Frau" und "Gattin"?

Tags: difference, politeness

Es gibt so einen Cartoon von Loriot, den ich jetzt auf Anhieb nicht gefunden habe, wo in der Bildunterschrift in etwa steht (es geht um Höflichkeit):

> [..] In dieser Situation hätte Herr X. sagen müssen "Das ist meine **Frau**." und nicht "Das ist meine **Gattin**."

Ich frage mich als (junger) Muttersprachler: Wo ist da der Unterschied? Gibt es einen (besonders in Bezug auf Höflichkeit und Etikette) oder gab es einen?
Oder macht sich Loriot hier nur mal wieder allgemein über Höflichkeiten lustig?

Comment: "Wenn meine Gattin aufwacht, nimmt sie gerne eine Tasse Tee. Mit etwas Gebäck." - Das ist aus dem Hallmackenreuter-Sketch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOIn2XMESlc

Comment: @tofro Den meine ich nicht, kenne ihn aber auch. Du hast aber recht, hier spielt Loriot auch mit den beiden Wörtern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erklärt hierzu:

> Das Wort *Gattin* gehört der gehobenen Stilschicht an. Außer in Österreich wird es nur für die Ehefrau eines anderen Mannes verwendet. Bei Bezug auf die eigene Ehefrau heißt es sonst *meine Frau.*

Demnach ist die Aussage in der Frage richtig. Statt „Das ist meine Gattin.“ hätte es heißen sollen „Das ist meine Frau.“

Comment: Das ist falsch, dass es nicht für die eigene Ehefrau verwendet wird.

Comment: @äüö Quellen dafür? Loong zitiert den Duden...

Comment: Was der Duden da schreibt, halte ich für Unsinn - Goethe (und der hat immer recht) schrieb schon: "ihr Geschrei durchdringt die Luft: meinen Gatten will ich wieder!", und Schiller pflichtet bei mit "ich kenne dich nicht mehr — ist dies Don Manuel, mein Gatte, mein Geliebter? ". Beide waren m.W. keine Österreicher.

Comment: @ixolius Quellen?: mein Leben, meine Sprache, mein soziales Umfeld. ;) Der Duden scheint das nicht richtig abzubilden.

Answer (score 3):

Der Sketch [Halmackenreuter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOIn2XMESlc) (hier geht's wohl um dasselbe wie den Cartoon, auf den du dich beziehst) spielt die ganze Zeit mit der Situation, die sich aus dem Gegensatz zwischen biederer Distanzierung vom Partner in einer sehr gewöhnlichen Situation (Möbelkauf) und der gleichzeitigen Intimität (gemeinsam in einem Bett liegen) ergibt.

*Gattin* gehört zu einer etwas gehobenen Sprache und bringt an sich zum Ausdruck "Ihr seid zusammen" und "es geht mich gar nix an, was ihr miteinander macht" (Das wird alleine dadurch deutlich, das sich das Amtsdeutsch genötigt sieht, mit "Ehegatten" den Begriff für verheiratete Paare weiter zu präzisieren). Verwendet es der Partner für seine Frau, schafft er damit offensiv Distanz zwischen sich und ihr und bringt im Sketch seine Biederkeit (oder würde man heute sagen Verklemmtheit?) zum Ausdruck. Wahrscheinlich deswegen sagt der Duden, dass man *Gattin* nicht für seine eigene Frau verwenden würde (womit ich persönlich nicht ganz einig bin). Nutzt man das so, *bekennt man sich ausdrücklich nicht zu seiner Partnerin* bzw. bringt zum Ausdruck, dass die Liebesbeziehung hier irrelevant ist.

Im Gegensatz dazu steht das später hinzukommende Paar - Er sagt "meine Frau", (obwohl sich später herausstellt, dass die beiden nicht verheiratet sind - "Ach was. Und wozu brauchen sie dann ein Doppelbett?"), baut damit klar die Distanz zwischen sich und seiner Partnerin ab.

Answer (score -4):

Ich kenne den Cartoon nicht, aber es könnte sein, dass er auf den Zusammenhang von "Gattin" mit "begatten" anspielt. In dem Fall beschriebe "meine Frau" a) das Geschlecht und b) den juristischen Familienstand, wohingegen "meine Gattin" zusätzlich noch angeben würde, dass der Sprecher und die Frau Sex miteinander haben.

Darüberhinaus würde ich die Verwendung von "Gattin" eher einer gehobenen Sprache zuordnen, und die Verwendung von "Frau" als Umgangssprache sehen. Es könnte also auch sein, dass die Komik daraus entsteht, dass eine dem Kontext unangemessene Sprachebene verwendet wird.

Comment: Die Idee des ersten Absatzes halte ich für abwegig, bei Loriot kommt Sexualität eher in den Bildern als in der Sprache vor. Zudem finde ich nicht, dass der Term "Gattin" sexuell aufgeladen ist. Der zweite Absatz sind Vermutungen, das hilft mir nicht weiter.

Comment: An sich ist "Gatte"/"Gattin" *distanzierter* und impliziert überhaupt keinen Sex - Schaut man sich die Sprachgeschichte an,findet man, dass es ursprünglich soviel wie "Gefährte" oder "Partner" hieß und durchaus auch für Kampfgefährten verwendet wurde. (Siehe Grimms Wörterbuch)

Comment: Die Aussagen, in "Gattin" würde "begatten" sehr deutlich mitschwingen und es sei gehobenere Sprache stellen einen Selbstwiderspruch dar. Beides gleichzeitig geht schlecht.